# why does exports and require() create a global variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

in db.js

```
exports = mongoose = require('mongoose')
```

in output.js

```
exports.log = function() {
    console.log(mongoose)
}
```

in app.js

```
var mg = require('./db.js')
var output = require('./output.js')
output.log() //output mongoose
```

If I change db.js to :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
exports = mongoose
```

Then output.log() cannot find mongoose anymore.

Answer (score 2):

It's a common error in javascript to declare several variables equal to each other in the same statement expecting that you declared a local variable.

```
var a = b = 42;
```

That will create a local variable `a` and a global variable `b`. First making `b` equal `42` and then `a` equal to `b`.

What you want to do is

```
var a = 42, b = 42;
```

or

```
var b = 42;
var a = b;
```

In your first db.js code, `exports` is already local to the module, doing `variable = mongoose = 'whatever';` creates a global variable called `mongoose`. In the second db.js code snipped, you declare `mongoose` as local.

Answer (score 0):

@DeaDEnD is right. The easy way to avoid this is by following this pattern:

```
var mongoose = module.exports = function () { }
```

`module` is already global due to the CommonJS spec so that's fine.